# Overcome illegal characters

Tags: errors

Bad value:

> `http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,regular,700,900|Open+Sans:300|Indie+Flower:regular|Oswald:300,regular,700&subset=latin,latin-ext`
>   for attribute href on element link:
>
> Illegal character in query: not a URL code point.

How to solve the above error and why does this error occur?

Comment: Where is this error occurring? PHP error log? W3C validator? Where is your code?

Answer (score 0):

Url encode the | (pipe characters) in the href attribute (%7C):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,300,800,700,400italic%7CPT+Serif:400,400italic%7CBree+Serif">
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22466913/google-fonts-url-break-html5-validation-on-w3-org[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22466913/google-fonts-url-break-html5-validation-on-w3-org)